# i can not install FM.IceLink.WebRTC in Xamarin.android project

Tags: xamarin.android

i can not install FM.IceLink.WebRTC in Xamarin.android project
it give me this error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Package FM.IceLink.WebRTC 2.9.32 is not compatible with monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1). Package FM.IceLink.WebRTC 2.9.32 supports:
  - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - wp8 (WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0)         0   
Error       Package FM.IceLink 2.2.0 is not compatible with monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1). Package FM.IceLink 2.2.0 supports:
  - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - win8 (Windows,Version=v8.0)
  - wp8 (WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0)         0   
Error       Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'videochattest'.           0   
Error       Package FM 2.0.0.5 is not compatible with monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1). Package FM 2.0.0.5 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)         0
```

and this one also

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not install package 'FM 2.0.0.5'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Comment: It is compatible, you need try other versions.

Comment: i tried to install minimum version of web fm.icelink.webrtc but not support.

Comment: Have you changed your compiler version, like 8.0, or others?

Comment: i changed it but failed to install it.

Comment: Hi @ZeeshanHaider did you found a solution? I meet a similar problem in a new Xamarin Android project with a NuGet package (AForge). I also tried to change the Target Framework but this didn't change anything. However, I can install the package in an older existing Android project without any problem.